# Recall Approval Request for a child object, when the Opportunity Stage equals Closed Lost or Closed Dead

Tags: trigger, method, approval-process

I wrote a below code attempting to Recall a record from a child object called "Price Request" which is in an approval process, when ever the parent object "Opportunity"  field name Opportunity stage is updated to Closed lost or closed Dead.(This is populated in child object Price request)

The problem is whenever I update my Stage of an Opportunity, the trigger below isnt kicking. The record is still in an approval process? What am I missing?

```
trigger ApprovalRecall on Price_Request__c (after update) 
{
    for(Price_Request__c a: Trigger.new) 
    { 

        if((a.Opportunity_Stage__c=='Closed Lost') || (a.Opportunity_Stage__c=='Closed - Dead')) 
        {

           List<ProcessInstanceWorkitem> piwi = [SELECT Id, ProcessInstanceId, ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId FROM ProcessInstanceWorkitem WHERE ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId =:a.id ];

           System.debug(piwi);

            for(ProcessInstanceWorkItem pid : piwi)

            {

                    system.debug('pid' + pid);

                    Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest pwr = new Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest();

                    pwr.setWorkitemId(pid.id);

                    pwr.setComments('Recalling all work approvals to roll back.');

                    pwr.setAction('Remove');

                    system.debug('pwr' + pwr);

                    Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.process(pwr);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The trigger should be on opportunity, check for stage then query related price request and then query approval process for those price request and withdraw those.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please tell me now how can I update my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create trigger on opportunity

```
trigger ApprovalRecall on opportunity (after update) 
{
    set<Id> setOppId = new set<Id>();
    for(opportunity a: Trigger.new) 
    { 

        if((a.Opportunity_Stage__c=='Closed Lost') || (a.Opportunity_Stage__c=='Closed - Dead')) 
        {
          setOppId.add(a.Id); 
        }
    }
    set<Id> setPrice_RequestId = new set<Id>();
    for(Price_Request__c objPrice_Request:[SELECT Id FROM Price_Request__c  WHERE opportunityId IN: setOppId])
    {
         setPrice_RequestId.add(objPrice_Request.Id);
    }
    List<ProcessInstanceWorkitem> piwi = [SELECT Id, ProcessInstanceId, ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId FROM ProcessInstanceWorkitem WHERE ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId IN:setPrice_RequestId ];

   System.debug(piwi);

    for(ProcessInstanceWorkItem pid : piwi)

    {

            system.debug('pid' + pid);

            Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest pwr = new Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest();

            pwr.setWorkitemId(pid.id);

            pwr.setComments('Recalling all work approvals to roll back.');

            pwr.setAction('Remove');

            system.debug('pwr' + pwr);

            Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.process(pwr);

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi , Can you please help me again with that code. It's not hitting the recall method actually. I need very urgently to solve this. I tried a lot with the modified code too.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008vvSIAQ

Comment: Hi Vigneswaran G, hope you are doing good. I didn't exactly get that trigger work done. I am strucked somewhere. Can you please help me with online support?

Comment: Hi @sneha what is the issue?